# Loading a C plugin system with JNI: undefined symbol

Tags: java, c, dll

I'd like to run my C plugin system within a Java program in Linux, I've written the binding and the library loads fine in my Java program.

The plugin system provide a command for loading plugins, that command is wrapped to Java so I can call i in my Java shell and it works.

The problem comes when plugins try to run command from the plugin system, I get an undefined symbol error. However, I've carefully linked all the functions used by the plugins to the library, the system is compiled using `-fPIC` and `-shared`. I've also taken a look at the symbolic table with `objdump -T` and the functions are listed.

I think the process is a bit insane, I load C code that load C code in Java... Is it possible?

If someone have ever encountered this problem or would like to share ideas about possible solutions I would be really thankful.

Thank you.

*Edit*: I've tried to mimic my program as best as I could in this example. I also get an error but it is quite different.

```
// plugin_system.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int load_and_run_plugin() {
  void *lib = dlopen("/home/kowa/code/c/test_dir/jni/plug/plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (lib == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open library.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  void (*plug_func)(void) = dlsym(lib, "plug_function");
  if (plug_func == NULL) {
    dlclose(lib);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find plugin function.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  plug_func();
  return 0;
}

// PluginSystem.c
#include "PluginSystem.h"
#include "plugin_system.h"

/*
 * Class:     PluginSystem
 * Method:    cmdPlug
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PluginSystem_cmdPlug
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass this)
{
  printf("Calling load_and_run function...\n");
  load_and_run_plugin();
  printf("End of call to load_and_run function\n");
}

// plugin_user_api.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void verbose_stdout(char *str)
{
  printf("%s", str);
}

void (*verbose) (char *str) = verbose_stdout;

// plugin.c
#include "plugin_user_api.h"

int plug_function() {
  verbose("I'm a plugin and I use external functions.\n");
  return 0;
}

// PluginSystem.java
public class PluginSystem
{
  static { 
    System.load("/home/kowa/code/c/test_dir/jni/plug/plugin_system.so");
  }
  public static native void cmdPlug();

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    PluginSystem.cmdPlug();
  }
}

// Makefile
JAVA_HOME      = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
C_INCLUDE_PATH = $(JAVA_HOME)/include $(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
INCLUDE        = $(foreach i, $(C_INCLUDE_PATH), -I$i)
CFLAGS         = -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99

all:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c plugin.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,plugin.so -shared -o plugin.so plugin.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -fPIC -c plugin_system.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -fPIC -c plugin_user_api.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -fPIC -c PluginSystem.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,plugin_system.so -shared -o plugin_system.so plugin_system.o plugin_user_api.o PluginSystem.o
    sed -i "s:System.load(.*):System.load(\"$(shell echo `pwd`)/plugin_system.so\"):" PluginSystem.java
    javac PluginSystem.java


clean:
    rm *.o *.so *.class
```

Output:

```
Calling load_and_run function...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=1653, tid=0x00007f01c76a2700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kowa/code/c/test_dir/jni/plug/core or core.1653
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/kowa/code/c/test_dir/jni/plug/hs_err_pid1653.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[2]    1653 abort (core dumped)  java PluginSystem
```

The log file is damn long (654 lines!) so don't blame on me for not posting it !

Comment: I don't see any reason why something like what you are trying to do would not be possible.  As for what is going wrong in your particular case, you haven't really given us anything to go on.  Your chances of getting help (or of helping yourself) would be greatly increased by your preparing a [mcve].

Comment: I've tried to take the essence of the system in the example added in the post, but I get a different error so I may have made a mistake in that example.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code worked for me, with the following caveats:

- I ran `javah` to produce my own version of `PluginSystem.h`, and I wrote my own `plugin_system.h`, since these were not posted
- I changed the hardcoded shared library paths to something appropriate to my local system.
- For convenience, I merged `plugin_user_api.c` into `plugin.c` and dropped `plugin_user_api.h` (which wasn't provided anyway)
- I rewrote your `Makefile` in more idiomatic style

If I build the native library, plugin, and Java class then running it produces this result:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java PluginSystem
Calling load_and_run function...
I'm a plugin and I use external functions.
End of call to load_and_run function
```

---

### Update:

I am able to replicate your problem if instead of merging `plugin_user_api.c` into `plugin.c`, I instead merge it into `plugin_system.c`.  In this case I can achieve the result that a C driver program is able to load the plugin, but Java fails to do so.  This suggests that Java is loading the library with the `RTLD_LOCAL` flag, so that its symbols are not exposed to subsequently-loaded libraries, such as the plugin.

There are at least three possible solutions:

- interpose another loader between Java and `plugin_system.so` to enable you to control the scope of `plugin_system.so`'s symbols.
- move all support functions needed by plugins out of plugin_system.so and into a separate dynamic library that any and all plugins can link to
- Relieve plugins from needing to link dynamically against the plugin system by instead having the plugin system initialize them with pointers to the needed functions and data

Of those, the first requires the least modification of your existing code, but the last is safest and most consistent with Java's intentional efforts to *avoid* exposing the library's dynamic symbols.  Indeed, you might consider making your plugin system do the same, to reduce the risk of plugins interfering with each other.

Here is a variation on your original code that demonstrates the third approach.  It adds a per-plugin initialization function that must be called after the plugin is loaded; this avoids any need for changes to the signature of any existing plugin function.  This variation also avoids exposing the plugin's symbols to other libraries that Java (or C) happens to load.  No changes are required on the Java side:

***plugin_system.h***

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_SYSTEM_H
#define PLUGIN_SYSTEM_H

struct plugin_context {
    void (*verbose) (char *str);
};

#endif
```

***plugin_system.c***

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "plugin_system.h"

typedef int (*init_function)(struct plugin_context *);

static void verbose_stdout(char *str)
{
  printf("%s", str);
}

static struct plugin_context context = { .verbose = verbose_stdout };

int load_and_run_plugin() {
  void *lib = dlopen("/home/kowa/code/c/test_dir/jni/plug/plugin.so",
      RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
  if (lib == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open library.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  init_function plug_init = dlsym(lib, "plug_init");
  if (plug_init == NULL) {
    dlclose(lib);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find plugin initialization function.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  plug_init(&context);  // error checking omitted

  void (*plug_func)(void) = dlsym(lib, "plug_function");
  if (plug_func == NULL) {
    dlclose(lib);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find plugin function.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  plug_func();         // error checking omitted
  return 0;
}
```

***plugin.c***

```
include <stdio.h>
#include "plugin_system.h"

static void (*verbose) (char *str);

int plug_init(struct plugin_context *context) {
  verbose = context->verbose;
  return 0;
}

int plug_function() {
  if (verbose) {
    verbose("I'm a plugin and I use external functions.\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The example I posted isn't quite accurate, it may works on smaller project I don't know but in my project the linker can't resolve links to functions in the plugin system library from. A possible solution is to send functions pointers to the plugin, the drawback of this is that if a function call another function from the same stage the linker still fails.

Comment: It seems that `System.load` load the library in a way that symbols are only present in the same namespace and plugins loaded doesn't have a natural access to that namespace, the problem is that we can't give it any option. Someone told that maybe adding one more stage in the process, a C library loaded by JNI which role would be to load the plugin system with the option `RTLD_GLOBAL` could solve the problem. I'll try this but if someone has any clue on the subject I would really appreciate it. PS: it fails with the same big java error like above, it's like the linker try to access to the jvm.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto, I have substantially revised and extended my answer.  After considering your comment, I was able to reproduce a failure to load the plugin.  I now suggest several possible solutions and offer a variation on your code that implements the one I most recommend.

Comment: It was tricky to understand what's going on and make a decent example, finally you've understood it, thank you ! I've just tried your last solution before my last comment, like I said it works great on small example like this, but you'll get error as soon as the callback functions call other functions! So it's an acceptable answer if you pass basic functions only.
About the loader solution, the loader is loaded with RTLD_GLOBAL, pugins could then be loaded with RTLD_LOCAL, why would there be any collision ?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto, neither my understanding of dynamic linking nor my experiments support your objection.  The linker resolves dynamic function names in the scope appropriate for the shared object in which they are referenced.  So, for example, if I add another function to `plugin_system.c` and make `verbose_stdout()` call that function, then that call is successfully resolved and performed when the plugin runs under Java.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto as for the approach of interposing another loader, even if the plugin system loads plugins with `RTLD_LOCAL`, the plugin system's own symbols are exposed to the whole Java VM process.  You cannot provide for plugins to see them without allowing the whole process to see them.  This is exactly what Java is trying to avoid, and I cannot recommend circumventing its efforts in this way.